# What is the simplest way to pause spring boot rabbit mq consumer?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-rabbit

Is there a simple a simple way to pause the spirng boot AMPQ and resume is after some time??

i'm using spring boot verison 2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a `@RabbitListener` method, give it an `id` attribute and stop/start it via the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` `@Bean`.

```
registry.getListenerContainer("myListenerId").stop();
```

If you created the listener container yourself then it can be stopped and started directly.